# What is the correct case for 'of' for a 16th century word for 'bad/difficult' woman?

Tags: grammatical-case

In a letter from Willibald Pirckheimer in 1500 addressed to Johann
Tscherte, Pirkheimer refers to Agnes Dürer as a 'pos Weyb'. I understand this means something like a difficult woman.  If you wanted to say a something like *pages of a 'pos Weyb'*, would you use *Blätter des pos Weybes*? I know Blätter may seem like an odd choice, but I am mostly interested in the "des pos Weybes" part.  Is the case correct?  Is adding the 'es' correct on Weyb?

Comment: Could you post a citation or include the full sentence for context? I'm pretty sure that "pos" does not exist in modern Standard German; perhaps it's a misspelling or dialect. Or perhaps it's an old form of "böse"? In any case, German adjectives are declined according to case (among other things), so it seems unlikely that "pos/böse/whatever" would be unchanged in the genitive. English Wikipedia mentions the enmity between  Pirckheimer and Agnes Dürer, but it's not in the corresponding article in German Wikipedia.

Comment: What is ` Pages of a 'pos Weyb'` supposed to mena?

Answer (score 4):

It's probably "pös Weyb" where *pös* is *böse* (bad, evil) in modern German.

The *des* is the genitive article, genitive indeed being the correct case here. In modern German, it would be *des bösen Weibes* or probably rather *der bösen Frau*.

Comment: My understanding is that "Weib" was not a derogatory term until recently, So "Weyb" would just mean "woman", possibly "wife", with no negative connotation. That puts a lot of weight on the meaning of this mysterious word "pos"/"pös". Btw, "Poes Weib" was Virginia Eliza Poe, but I'm pretty sure that's a completely different person.

Comment: I extended my answer to include the modern word for woman without negative connotation.

Comment: @RDBury That is correct, yes.

Answer (score 3):

In contemporary German "pos weyb" means "böses Weib". It refers to [Agnes Dürer](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agnes_D%C3%BCrer), the wife of the famous painter Albrecht Dürer. It was Pirckheimer who described her as "pos Weyb". Quote from [here](https://www.nuernberg.de/imperia/md/nuernbergkultur/dokumente/veranstaltungsinfos/duerers_nachbarschaft.pdf):

> Agnes Frey (1475– 1538)
> Für Dürer war die Ehe mit Agnes eine glänzende Partie: Ihre Familie war reich, Mutter Anna gehörte einem alten Patriziergeschlecht an. Aber auch per
> sönliche Bekanntschaft spielte sicher eine Rolle: Immerhin waren beide nur einen Steinwurf voneinander aufgewachsen und kannten sich von klein
> auf. Als Albrechts „Managerin“ pflegte Agnes Kundenkontakte und verkaufte seine Grafiken auf dem Markt. Das „pos weyb“, als das Dürers Freund
> Pirckheimer sie dargestellt hat, gehört wohl ins Reich der Legenden.

> Agnes Frey (1475– 1538)
> Dürer’s marriage to Agnes counted as “an excellent match” for the painter. Agnes’s family was rich and through her mother Anna she belonged to one of the ancient patrician dynasties of the city. But there is no doubt that personal acquaintance and inclination also played a role in the union. Husband and wife had, after all, grown up within a stone’s throw of each other and known each other since childhood. Agnes also played the role of Albrecht’s “manager”, cultivating potential customers and selling his drawings on the market. The “ill-natured woman” that Dürer’s friend
> Pirckheimer once called her surely belongs to the realm of myth.

Calling Agnes Dürer a "pos Weyb" was most likely a defamation. In the [above Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agnes_D%C3%BCrer) one can find the reference

- Corine Schleif: "Das pos weyb Agnes Frey Dürer: Geschichte ihrer Verleumdung und Versuche der Ehrenrettung," ("The Bad Wife Agnes Frey Dürer: History of her Defamation and Attempts at her Rehabilitation"), in: Mitteilungen des Vereins für Geschichte der Stadt Nürnberg 86 (1999), 47-79

See also [here](https://www.academia.edu/8219331/Corine_Schleif_Das_pos_weyb_Agnes_Frey_D%C3%BCrer_Geschichte_ihrer_Verleumdung_und_Versuche_der_Ehrenrettung).

You ask

> If you wanted to say a something like pages of a 'pos Weyb', would you use Blätter des pos Weybes?

I am not sure what you want to say, but I guess you mean the pages of Pirckheimer's letter on which the phrase "pos Weyb" occurs. Im German this means

> Die Seiten, auf denen Agnes Dürer als "pos Weyb" bezeichnet wird.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, we are talking about German as it was used 500 years ago, and the language has changed significantly over such a long timespan.

With modern grammar, things would be a bit different:

"Blätter des pös Weybes" would be written "Blätter des bösen Weibs" or "Blätter des bösen Weibes" (less common, but also correct) if using the most similar words, regardless of any change of meaning or connotation.

Let's analyze the differences:

- "des" still needs the genitive case.
- The adjective "pös" needs a genitive ending "-en" nowadays.
- The noun "Weyb" still gets a genitive ending, and it can be "-s" or "-es" nowadays.